# Есть ли разница между методами, определенными внутри класса и внутри заголовочного файла?

Tags: c++, функции, header

Здравствуйте.

Допустим, в некотором заголовочном файле у меня есть

```
Struct A
{
    //метод foo является inline?
    void foo()
    {
    }

    //метод bar?
    void bar();
};

void A::bar(){}
```

Если метод является инлайновым, то при многократном подключении вышеописанного заголовочного файла будет создаваться несколько копий функции foo(), а затем будет выбрана только одна. Т.е. foo будет компилироваться несколько раз.

А что будет с функцией bar() ? Она не является inline, но определена внутри хедера, при этом многократные подключения хедер файла не вызывают ошибки

Answer (score 2):

Нет, `foo()` будет inline, так что это будет одна функция.

А вот `bar` при этом нарушит правило одного определения, потому что она не объявлена как inline, и будут проблемы при кормпоновке приложения из нескольких файлов - в каждом будет свой `bar()`. При компиляции отдельных файлов проблем не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Всякая функция, определенная внутри объявления класса, является автоматически inline- функцией, если только это допустимо.

Фунция bar определена вне класса, поэтому она не inline.

Для избежания повторного подлючения используется [include guard](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

```
#ifndef H_HEADERNAME
 #define H_HEADERNAME
...code...
 #endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Никакой разницы между ними не будет кроме того, что `foo()` неявно считается встраиваемой, а `bar()` нет. Также стоит добавить, что встраиваемость функции в Си++ является для компилятора рекомендацией, а не обязательным указанием. То есть компилятор сам принимает решение нужно ли встраивать функцию вне заивисмости от того явно или нет она объявлена встраиваемой.